# Find the limit of of such a sequence defined by recurrence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So I need to find the limit of such a sequence defined by recurrence:

- $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$
- $a_2=1$
- $a_n= \frac{1}{2}a_{n-1} + \sqrt{a_{n-2} } $  for every $n \in \mathbb{N} \geq 3$

I have calculated some elements of that seqence and those are:

- $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$
- $a_2=1$
- $a_3 = 1+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
- $a_4= \frac{{3}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$
- $a_5= \frac{{3}}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{8} + \sqrt{1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$

So I know that the values fo next elements of the sequence grow really slow. But what do I do next?

Comment: If you can show the limit exists $a=\lim a_n$, then the recursion formula gives $a=\frac12 a+\sqrt{a}$, from which you can solve for $a$. So what you need to do is to prove the existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your next step should be proving that this increasing sequence has an *upper bound*. Then we can say that the sequence has a limit because of *Completeness of the real numbers*. We can prove this by induction.

If $a_{n-2}\leq4$ and $a_{n-1}\leq4$, then $$a_n=\frac{1}2a_{n-1}+\sqrt{a_{n-2}}\leq\frac{1}2\cdot4+\sqrt{4}=2+2=4$$
so $a_n\leq 4$. This holds for base case ($n=3$) since $a_1\leq4$ and $a_2\leq4$.

Hence it is proven that the limit exists. Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, then the recurrence relation gives you $$L=\frac{1}2L+\sqrt{L}\implies \frac{1}2L=\sqrt{L}\implies L=4$$

Comment: That's great, but how do I know that the limit is precisely 4? And not 3.9? Why did you take 4?

Comment: It doesn't have to be 4. In fact, in the proof, you can take any number that is greater than 4. Then you can prove that $a_n\leq 4$ and say that $a_n$ is less than the number you take. This is still valid since you've still proved that the sequence has an upper bound.

Comment: In my answer, I just directly take $4$ because I notice that $4=\frac{1}2\cdot4+\sqrt4$.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The last equation makes you sure that the limit is 4 because the limit of every sequence in that recurrsion must be the same, right?

Comment: If we take $3.9$, then it is actually impossible to prove that $a_n\leq 3.9$ holds for all $n$ because even though we have $a_{n-1}\leq3.9$ and $a_{n-2}\leq3.9$, $a_n\leq 3.9$ won't always hold.