# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}\right)$, is my solution wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I needed to calculate: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}\right)$$

First of all I saw that it won't be possible to do that in any traditional way and actually calculate the limit, because of the form of expression. I mean - it's a sum with sqares on $n$ so I can't use Stolz lemma that easy. But, I thoght, that the solution is probably $0$, because probably every element of the sum is $0$ when $n \implies \infty$ and the limitation of sum in $\infty$ = sum of limitations in $\infty$. So I just went with that and decided to prove that using induction.

My base is:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} = 0$$

My assumption:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +...+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n}}\right) = 0$$

My induction:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}\right) = 0 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}) = 0$$

So the limit is:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}\right) = 0$$

But then my grader at university said that at first sight it looks totaly wrong but he actualy needs to think about it a bit. So here is my question - is that wrong? How is that wrong?

Ok, thank you for your answers. I thought I can solve that exercise that way because I asked not long ago very similar question on that forum: [Find the limit of of such a sequence defined by recurrence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910536/find-the-limit-of-of-such-a-sequence-defined-by-recurrence/3910547?noredirect=1#comment8065219_3910547)

Because of your answers I think that the problem is actually that in this case I am dealing with a SUM of elements, am I right (or it the answer that I got in other case wrong?)?

Comment: You cannot split limit on variable amount of summands - only on fixed number.

Comment: If you add $\frac 1 n$ $n$ times what do you get? Can you find the limit of this sum by taking limit for each term? When the number of terms is not fixed you cannot take the limit for each term separately.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question then, because it still works in my opinion. I can split them juest in 3 parts: base (first one), assumption (all but one), induction (all of them).

Comment: How many terms are there?  Can you bound the terms above and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The others already told you why your solution is wrong. I am going to show you how to actually compute this limit (and please bear in mind that this is a standard trick for such limits).
Obviously, $\displaystyle n^2+1\le n^2+k \le n^2+2n+1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $k= \overline{1,2n+1}$. This is equivalent to saying that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\le \frac{1}{n^2+k}\le \frac{1}{n^2+1}$. After you take the square root and sum up all the inequlities you get that $\displaystyle \frac{2n+1}{n+1}\le \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le \frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and now by the squeeze theorem you may conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}=2.$

Comment: Wow, thank you very much Sir! I will try to use the squeeze theorem more often. Can you just tell me how did you get 2n + 1 on top of those 2 elements of inequality when between lines 4-5? Did you just write it by yourself because it fits your needs and is still true to the inequality?

Comment: @theboyboy You know that $\frac{1}{n+1}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ for all $k=\overline{1,2n+1}$. If you let $k=1,2,...,2n+1$ and you sum up these $2n+1$ inequalities you get precisely the inequality on the $5^\text{th}$ row.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly,
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + k}} \le \frac{1}{n}
$$
for $k=1,2,\ldots,2n+1$. Hence
$$
\frac{2n+1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}<\frac{2n+1}{n}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n}=2.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 2}} +\cdots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 +2n + 1}}\to 2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

By an induction like this you can correctly prove that for any **constant** $k$,
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + \dots + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}} \right) = 0.
$$
But there is no value of $k$ for which this sum of a fixed number of terms will turn into the sum in the question, which has a variable number of terms.

Going in the other direction, you can "bite off" any number of terms, and show that
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}} + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2}} + \dots + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}} \right) =    \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k}} + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+k+1}} + \dots + \frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}} \right).
$$
But there is no value of $k$ which will reduce this to the limit that you've called the base case, because the number of terms will always keep growing with $n$.

---

In fact, since there are $2n+1$ terms in the sum, and each one of them is at least $\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+2n+1}} = \frac1{n+1}$, that the sum is equal to at least $\frac{2n+1}{n+1} = 2 - \frac1{n+1}$, and therefore the limit is at least $2$, not $0$. Think about what kind of upper bound we can put on the sum in the same way...

Answer (score 1):

Using generalized harmonic numbers
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+k}}=H_{n^2+2 n+1}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-H_{n^2}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Using the asymptotics
$$H_p^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{p}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{p}}$$ and continuing with Taylor series
$$a_n=2-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$